# asp.net web forms single row table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a page that has data as multiple rows, but I want this to be in one row with multiple "columns" instead. I want to use an asp:someElementX since my backend logic can stay the same (if possible)

The current state is:

```
data1
data2 
data3
```

My desired state is

```
data1 data2 data3
```

I currently use `<asp:Table ID="Data" runat="server" />`
what is the equivilent to asp:Table for what I am looking for?

Comment: You mean like pivot?

Comment: GridView is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell
        ...
        ...
    >
    <asp:TableCell
        ...
        ...
    >
    <asp:TableCell
        ...
        ...
    >
</asp:TableRow>
```

Should be possible to implement with your back end logic.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.aspx for code examples.